# Laravel Queue - Replacing lots of small mysql updates

Tags: php, mysql, caching, laravel, increment

I regularly run this fairly common MySQL updates:

```
UPDATE content SET views = views+1 WHERE id = xxx
```

This happens on most of the major pages (content could be anything such as articles, forum topics, downloads, videos etc), as you can tell it's just incrementing the count of the number of times that piece of content has been viewed.

To avoid doing an update on every single page I was thinking of using a Queue.

However what I would need to do is not queue every single update, but increment the count in the queue. What's the best way to do this?

For instance I couldn't just do this:

```
Queue::push('incrementCount', array('content' => $content));
```

Because it would still wind up doing 1000 individual updates. I would need somewhere to save the count of how many times it has been viewed and then do the update statement once (an hour, or every 15 minutes or something)

I've thought about using APC cache but I worry that this is dangerous since the cache could be lost, it is exactly that "a cache" and shouldn't be relied upon to store important data.

Comment: I don't see the problem with updating each item individually (via a queue) - Is there any particular reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: Well i'm seeing the that query alot in the slow query log and because it happens so frequently i'm it's too many queries hitting the same row. Would a daemon process doing the update being that much better than a user?

Comment: That's strange... That query shouldn't be that slow to execute (I would expect less than 100ms). Is your example the whole query or are there other clauses (WHERE, ORDER BY etc)? Also, if your content table is changing often you might need to run OPTIMIZE TABLE if you haven't for a while. Using a queue listener wouldn't improve the speed the query is executed, but at least you're not blocking the page load while that query runs so definitely better in that sense. Might also be a good idea to use UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY for this too so you're not blocking any other queries while it executes.